# React JS - Error when using this. state next to the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am receiving the following errors:
1.Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: array.
Check your code at ButtonMenu.js:432.
2.Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

It appears to have an issue with this line of code:

```
<ProductList products={this.state.products} />
```

Is that not the correct way to use this? Here is the full code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";  



const  ProductList =[
    {
        id:0,
        category:"accessories",
        image:"./prod_images/accessory1.jpg",
        product: "product1",
        description: "product1",
        price: 0.00
},
```

];

//There are 50+ of these objects. I cut them out to keep this short.

```
const CATEGORIES = ['All', 'Men', 'Women', 'Jerseys', 'Shirts', 'Accessories', 'Collectables'];




class ButtonMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        products: ProductList || []
      };
    }
  
    getCategory = category => {
      const filter = ProductList.filter(d => d.category === category);
      if (filter) {
        this.setState({products: filter});
      }
    };
    render() {
      return (
       <>
          <div className="button Menu-container">
            <ProductList products={this.state.products} />
            {CATEGORIES.map(item => (
                <button
                key ={item.toString()}
                className="main-btn"
                onClick={() => this.getCategory(item.toLowerCase())}
                value={item.toLowerCase()}>
                {item}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
          </>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default ButtonMenu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render an array of objects as it was a react component. That is why you are getting the error because it's something against the rules. So, instead of rendering the `ProductList` you probably want to do something like this:

```
<div>
 {this.state.products.map((product) => {
   //here you render whatever you want to render about each product
 })}
</div>
```

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductList` is not a React component, therefore you can't call it like one. You would rather create a component that accepts the array of products and renders them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`ProductList` is not a component instead it is an array. If it is an array then you should map it.

You are using `ProductList` as a React component which is not allowed

```
<ProductList products={ this.state.products } />. // NOT ALLOWED
```

where

```
const ProductList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    category: "accessories",
    image: "./prod_images/accessory1.jpg",
    product: "product1",
    description: "product1",
    price: 0.00
  },
];
```